# Redundant <path> element inside an svg file

Tags: svg

Thw following two SVG markups render identically:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path style={inputAdornmentIcon} d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"/>
      <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path style={inputAdornmentIcon} d="M12 12c2.21 0 4-1.79 4-4s-1.79-4-4-4-4 1.79-4 4 1.79 4 4 4zm0 2c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v2h16v-2c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z"/>
    </svg>
```

Any idea what the second path element (`<path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>`) in the first version actually does?

Comment: It's a rectangle that covers all the svg canvas. Google's icons are always using a rectangle like this for a background, but the rectangle is the first path.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages of skipping that path entirely in my component markup?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using Google's icon without the rectangle. It's always a good idea to simplify the markup.

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I'll be able to accept and close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra path in your code is a a rectangle that covers all the svg canvas. As I've commented Google's icons are always using an extra rectangle like this for a background, but the rectangle is coming first. It's always a good idea to remove redundant elements and to simplify the markup.